# Can't read from xlsx file with rubyXL

Tags: ruby, excel, xlsx, rubyxl

I'm trying to work with excel files(xlsx) in ruby using [rubyXl](https://github.com/gilt/rubyXL). I have no problem writing but can't get to output the content of a cell.

```
require 'rubyXL'
workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
workbook.worksheets[0].add_cell(5,5,"test")
workbook.write("file3.xlsx")
getcell = RubyXL::Parser.parse("file3.xlsx")
print getcell[0][5][5]
```

When I run it in cmd I just get this and it changes every time I run the code.

```
D:\KEA\1.semester\Exams\IT exam>ruby test.rb
#<RubyXL::Cell:0x2e4a600>
```

SOLUTION:

After reading a few more times I found the answer in

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rubyXL/1.1.12/RubyXL/Cell

It should have been

```
print getcell[0][5][5].value
```

Comment: Everything is correct: you want to print the instance of `Cell` and you get it printed. Try to take a look at the documentation on `Cell` class within `rubyXL`, it should’ve a method for retrieving a value itself.

Comment: After I looked for the 5th time I found it. Had to add .value cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a few more times I found the answer in

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rubyXL/1.1.12/RubyXL/Cell

It should have been

```
print getcell[0][5][5].value
```